# How to convert std_logic to unsigned in an expression

Tags: vhdl

So if wanted to assign a std_logic to a 1-bit usnigned I could just write...

```
signal X : unsigned(0 downto 0);
signal Y : std_logic;

X(0) <= unsigned(Y)
```

But what s the best way to convert a std_logic to an unsigned when used in an expression.
That is to say, without directly doing an assignment to a signal of type unsigned.

The scenario I have is this.  I have two flags A and B that are signals of type std_logic.
Each flag has a strobe (A_valid , B_valid) of type std_logic that assert for 1 clock cycle each time their flag (A , B) is valid.
I have a counter (CNT) that is a signal of type unsigned that must count the number of times that either of the flags is '1'.
On any given clock cycle I must incrment CNT by 0, 1, or 2 depending on how many flags are 1.

Here is the straight forward way of doing it with an "if" statement.

```
signal A       : std_logic;
signal A_valid : std_logic;
signal B       : std_logic;
signal B_valid : std_logic;
signal CNT     : unsigned;

if rising_edge(clk) then
  if (A and A_valid and B and B_valid) = '1' then
    CNT <= CNT + 2;
  elsif (A and A_valid) = '1' then
    CNT <= CNT + 1;
  elsif (B and B_valid) = '1' then
    CNT <= CNT + 1;
  end if;
end if;
```

The problem with the code above is that it doesn't generalize very well since the number of cases goes up exponentially with the number of flags.  For example if I had 5 flags I would have to write out 32 branches in the IF statement.

A more compact way of representing the same thing using an aggregate and a type mark is...
This is better becasue I just write one expression for each flag.

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
  CNT <= CNT + unsigned'(0=> A AND A_valid) + unsigned'(0=> B AND B_valid);
end if;
```

Are there any other built-in ways (other than writing a function) to convert std_logic to unsigned in an expression in VHDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to concatenate the std_logic with a null array,  yielding an array of length 1.

`Cnt <= cnt + ("" & a_valid);`

It should be able to work out the type from the context,  otherwise you may need to qualify it with unsigned'

Comment: I like this.  Its a good alternative.  It would probably have to be written (unsigned("") & (A and A_valid)).

Comment: like I said, it will depend on context. No qualification is needed here because there is only one possible "+" function - unsigned + unsigned. So (""&A_Valid) becomes an unsigned(0 to 0).